# iPhone - How to send image + text to Facebook using ShareKit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

As per the requirement in my app, I want to send an image and text (dynamic; written by user) to Facebook. I have already written the code for sending the image which is as follows:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00%d",currentIndex_+1];
NSString *imageIndex = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"png"];
NSLog(@"image index:%@",imageIndex);
// NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageIndex];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageIndex] title:@"sent via iphone"];
[NSClassFromString(@"SHKFacebook") performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
```

but now I also want to send text (dynamic) with this image. How can I send text with image?

Comment: why don't you use NSString stringWithFormat: i.e.` NSString *var=@"aaa"; SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageIndex] title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@",var,@"Sent via iSLP Break Roomi iPhone App"]];`

Comment: but this will be static text I want to send text written by user

Comment: you can put the text that user had written in NSString *var in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy. Just make sure to #import the SHKItem and SHKFaceBook

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
SHKItem *itemToShare = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Some title if you want to"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:itemToShare];
```

Comment: but I want to send dynamic(written by user) text not static

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@ %@\",\"href\":\"\",\"caption\":\"descriptoin\",\"description\":\"\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"**http://example.com/webservices/images/img.png**\",\"href\":\"http://%@/\"}]}",name,msg,url];
```

replace this code with dialog.attachment which is inside the SHKFacebook.m and replace your image url/path which i am written in bold letter.

and post your text using the code :

```
SHKItem  *item1 =[SHKItem text:@"hello"];<p>
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item1];
```